# Visual C forces unused import, pulled in by a library

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, linker, dllimport

Recently updated a project from Visual Studio 2010 to 2015, and we ran into a weird link-time problem.

We build our project for both amd64 and x86, and debug and release modes.
The project has 2 dependencies, let's call them **libA** and **libB**.
We have some custom post-build scripts in place, that do some verifications on the binaries (such as check for NX and SEH flags, among other things).
Using this script, we also verify the imported DLL's and their imported functions, to keep static imports as few as possible and try to resolve the extra ones trough dynamic load (for backwards compatibility).

After the migration, we managed to build everything in every possible configuration, but in **DEBUG** mode (and in DEBUG mode only) the resulting binary - due to code present in **libA** - pulls in some imports - let's call it **dllA** - that are actually not used, and as such are not desired to be present.
**libB** introduces no problems - although it's a very simple library.

The reason why **libA** is pulling those imports in are because it is a multi-purpose library, used by some other projects, and it has some code, that calls functions from **dllA**, but in our project we do not call those dllA-export-calling-functions at all.
I also disassembled the dll with IDA and found out, that those functions are sitting in the binary, completely disconnected from the rest of the code from the binary - they are not referenced at all.

After some searching around, and trying to link the **RELEASE** version of **libA** to our **DEBUG** build of our project, i found out, that the imports from **dllA** are no longer pulled in, making me think, that the library configuration can be the problem.
I took the command line arguments for the debug and release build of the library, and compared them side-by-side, to find out the differences in configuration.
I managed to pin-point the problem to the Optimization setting (on the Optimization tab):

- for DEBUG mode, it's set to Disabled (**/Od**) by default
- for RELEASE mode, it's set to Maximize Speed (**/O2**)
- setting **Maximize Speed (/O2)** for **DEBUG** mode takes care of the problem - dllA is no longer imported

My problem is, that this is really counter-intuitive for debugging, as the compiler will optimize out too many things, possibly making debugging harder.

Before posting, i looked around everywhere, and also looked into in our main project's Linker->Optimization page, and the **References** option is set to **Yes (/OPT:REF)**, which should avoid linking of unused code, but it seems to me, that VS2015 completely ignored this setting on debug builds.

Comment: duplicate comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching found this article: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/the-most-underused-compiler-switches-in/240166599?pgno=6.

It turns out, that setting the option **/Gy (Enable Function-Level Linking)** in **libA** no longer causes unused APIs to be imported